# Advice on implementing security aspect of Java EE web application

Tags: security, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, model-view-controller

Simple question on which security type to use.
Using: `Java EE, EJB, JPA, TomEE, MVC-Servlets + JSP, MySQL`

I am working on a simple web app, and would like to implement "security part". This is my first bigger `Java EE` project, and I would like to ask for advice on implementing security.
I am storing informations about users in `mysql` database (table `user`, some fields: `username, password, user_type`...).

Reading about security in `Java EE` on the net, there are many new concepts I am not yet familiar with: `JAAS, declarative security, programmatic security, form based authentication, BASIC authentication, JASPIC` ...(I am aware what are authentication and authorization).

Because, i don't have much time, i am asking for simple advice which of these concepts should I focus on to implement security in my app? Requirement is that user authentication should be implemented with username and password, and authorization with session tracking.

Basicly, what is the appropriate approach to implementing security for these requirements?

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for form based security. It will enable you to authenticate and authorize users based on their usernames and roles as defined in database. Learn how to [configure JAAS with jBoss 7 and mysql](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/09/18/configure-jaas-jboss-7-1-mysql/) and [configure jdbcrealm with tomcat and mysql](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/07/configure-jdbcrealm-jaas-for-mysql-and-tomcat-7-with-form-based-authentication/)

Comment: Thanks, your article is simple and straight to the point, yet nicely explained.

Comment: I can't exactly blame you, but it's a petty people always have to resort to explaining this with proprietary things, where for many servers there's a standard solution as well (JASPIC, already mentioned by OP)

Comment: @Arjan Tijms I was also of the opinion that JAAS is a standard for implementing security. But, as you have explained it, in your blog on JASPIC, it isn't really vendor independent. For now, I will try to implement security in a simplest way, cause I am really running out of time to finish this project. But your blog has its place in my bookmarks folder.

Comment: what about logout, or getting the user currently logged in?